# Fading effect with QCPItemTracer

Tags: qt

I have been able to use QCPItemTracer to trace a specific point on my data when plotting. How do I achieve a fade out effect? That is, as the next point is plotted, the last n points fade out slowly. Does Qt provide such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this class of QCustomPlot but it should be easy to implement what you are asking for your self. You just need to keep track of the last `n` points. When it comes to plotting this is often referred to as *oscilloscope-type persistence*.

Fade out effect is usually achieved by gradually changing either the alpha channel or the color value of the item you want to affect. The first is relatively easy but requires alpha support (QCustomPlot does support it) and [decreases performance](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/performanceimprovement.html) of your plotting tool. The second requires you to calculate a gradient starting with the color the point was originally plotted with and going all the way up/down to whatever background color you have selected for your plot. The gradient step can directly be derived from `n`.

1. For every `n+1` point just iterate through the `n` points before that
2. For each of those points reduce the alpha or change the color

I'm presuming that fade out effect you want also needs to be distributed unequally among all points based on their age with point `n` (the youngest) being the least affected and point `0` (the oldest) being the most affected by the fade out effect like this (from left to right age of a point increase):

[image]